# Call "two" functions from a string stored in a variable PHP

Tags: php, mapping

I know how to call a function from a string stored in a variable, but I want to call an other function from the first function called.

Example :

```
$func1()->$func2()
```

But I want to pass just ONE string to my function which will do this like :

```
$this->arrayMapped($profilFonctionnalites->toArray(), "getFonctionnalites()->getId()");



public function arrayMapped($array, $columnToMap) {
    foreach ($array as $object) {
        $map[$object->$columnToMap()] = $object;
    }
    return $map;
}
```

How to do that while remaining in the idea of ​​being as generic as possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: Guess you’ll have to split this, so that you got the method names only, and then apply them one after the other, in a recursive fashion - the resulting object of one method call is what you need to call the next one on.

Comment: I guess something like this should basically work, `$temp = $object; foreach(['getFonctionnalites', 'getId'] as $methodName) { $temp = $temp->$methodName(); }` - temp variable so that you don’t overwrite your original $object, because you still need that. Just figure out how to get your input string parsed into an array of that form then. (Or maybe pass such an array in as parameter to begin with, instead of the “prosaic” form `getFonctionnalites()->getId()` - that doesn’t appear to offer any actual benefits here.)